# How can I know what type of encryption is used by my mobile phone?

Tags: gsm

I'm interested in finding out what kind of cipher is used on my Android phone. For example A5/1, A5/3 or is the GSM connection unencrypted. I was thinking about sending AT commands to the GSM modem (/dev/smd0), however I didn't find any command that would tell me this. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try the service menu if your phone supports it: dial `*#*#7378423#*#*` (`*#*#service#*#*`).